# Powershell: Variable assignment triggers module import

Tags: windows, powershell

This code works from the Powershell command line but generates an error when run from a script:

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
Set-ItemProperty $key Hidden 1
```

When I run it from my script, I get the following error:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer : The module 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER' could not be
loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module HKEY_CURRENT_USER'.
At C:\Users\mybitch\Desktop\VSS-Customize-Desktop.ps1:19 char:6
+ $key=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKEY_CURRENT_US...ersion\Explorer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
```

This is a simple assignment...Why would Powershell try to import `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` as a module? Why is the behavior so different from the Powershell command line?

Comment: `HKCU:` is a provider. You can check `Get-PSDrive` and you will see it. If it is not present PowerShell would attempt to load it in theory. Where are you running this script from? Not task scheduler is it?

Comment: I'm simply calling the script from an elevated Powershell command line.

Comment: Get-PSDrive shows HKCU is loaded. Why would it try to reload it and then fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message betrays the problem.  In your script, apparently you are doing this:

```
$key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
```

That is an invalid assignment.  You *should* be doing as you describe:

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
```

Comment: You are correct. The error was actually a few lines down in my code and was missing the quotes. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help - btw if someone provides a successful answer, you can click the little check box next to that answer to indicate that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the script you have the User Hive being loaded, for example if you are running it from a task scheduler you will need it to load a hive for it to have the effect that you want.